# Automatically assigning subdomains

Tags: php, apache

I would like to know how to automatically assign sub-domains like the way blogger or wordpress.com does. I've done some online research but I'm heading nowhere. For example if my site is www.msite.com and someone creates a blog under my domain, I'd like them to get the www.theirblog.msite.com. Please assist. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach would be to:

- Set up wild card DNS so that *.example.com resolves to the server
- Set up Apache so that the default virtual host is the one running your app (you would probably want a different virtual host for example.com and www.example.com that goes to your own website as opposed to your users' sites)
- Since you mention PHP, pay attention to `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: thank you so much, but how to assign the subdomains automatically is the issue

Comment: Assign to what? The user? You just have a column in the user table of your database (or just reuse the username).

Comment: to a new user just like the way blogger assigns a subdomain to a new blog created by a user.

Comment: Than, as I said, you just map the HTTP_HOST onto the username in your users table.

Comment: Let me research on it. May you have any clue of where I could get good tutorials for  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?

Comment: Tutorials?! It is a string containing a hostname. There is far too little to say about it to warent a tutorial.